# File_Get_Contents an Entire Array

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want the file_get_contents every single link in my array. Therefore, i Can apply a preg_match code which will then match all the first 20 characters in the first p tags detected.

my code is below:

```
 $links = array(0 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory", 1=>  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four");
   print_r($links);
  $link = implode(", " , $links);
  $html = file_get_contents($link);

  preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
  $res = get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
  echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one url at a time in `file_get_contents`. Combining the links will not work instead you need to loop the each link and get the content.

```
  $links = array(0 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory", 1=>  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four");
  print_r($links);

  foreach($links as $link){
    $html = file_get_contents($link);
    preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
    $res = get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
    echo $res;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use their API?

You can still use `file_get_contents` to retrieve the, well, contents, but you can decide on a format more suitable to your needs.

Their API is documented quite well, see: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

URLs will transform into something